# I can't get any variable to be recognized outside of its function (in this case "app.get" (node.js))

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the variable `var result` inside the `app.get` function, when I try to use `result` in the function `app.post` it won't recognize it `result is not defined` (terminal). They were all constants before and I turned them to variables, that still did not work. Here is the code:

```
   '''
   app.get("/", function(request, response){
      var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 1);
      var firstNumber = random ? (Math.random()*(10000)-5000).toFixed(2) : 
     (Math.round(Math.random()*(100))-50);
     var secondNumber = random ? (Math.random()*(10000)-5000).toFixed(2) : 
     (Math.round(Math.random()*(100))-50);
      var operations = random ? ["+", "-"] : ["*", "/"];

      var randomOperation = operations[Math.round(Math.random() * 1)];
      var expression = firstNumber + randomOperation + secondNumber;
      var resultNotInterger = eval(expression);
      var result = Number(resultNotInterger).toFixed(2);
      response.render("index.ejs", {
     firstNumber: firstNumber,
     secondNumber: secondNumber,
      randomOperation: randomOperation,
     result: result
      });
     });

    app.post("/", function(request, response){
    var clientResponse = Number(request.body.clientResponse).toFixed(2);
    response.redirect("/");
    console.log(result);
    });
    '''
```

Comment: A variable defined in one [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) can't be used in another scope. I think you need to do some reading on the basics.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct behavior of the variable scope. The scope of variables declared via `var` is `function`. So you have no access to variables from one function in another function except the closure case.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: So I guess I have to rewrite the code differently? or is there any command or any way to use that variable where I want to use it?

Comment: It depends on what you are expecting from this solution. For example, you can move the  `result` variable definition to shared scope of these handlers and in `get` handler only assign the value to the variable